# Deck of cards, cant figure out how to shuffle

Tags: c++

My code already makes the deck of cards, but how do i shuffle it? My shuffle function seems to not be working.
I may also have some errors elsewhere and if you can see them please let me know. It compiles and runs but it lists the cards in order.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Card{
public:
    int face;
    int suit;
    void setData(int f, int s){
        face = f;
        suit = s;
    }
    string toString(int F, int S){
        static string faces[13] = {"Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",       "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};
        static string suits[4] = {"Clubs", "Spades", "Diamonds", "Hearts"};
        string FandS = faces[F] + " of " + suits[S] + "\n";
        return FandS;
    }
};

class DeckOfCards:public Card{
public:
    Card deck[13][4];
    int currentCard;

    void shuffle(){
        srand (time(0));
        Card temp[13][4]; int R, r;
        for(int shuf=0; shuf<52; shuf++){
            for(int i=0; i<13; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
                    R = rand()%13;  
                    r = rand()%4;
                    temp[i][j] = deck[i][j];
                    deck[i][j] = deck[R][r];
                    deck[R][r] = temp[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    bool moreCards(){
        currentCard=52;
        currentCard--;
        if(currentCard>0){
            return true;
        }else 
            return false;
    }

    void dealCard(){
        for(int i=0; i<13; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
                cout << toString(i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    DeckOfCards(){  
        for(int i=0; i<13; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
                deck[i][j].setData(face, suit);
            }
        }
    }

};

int main(){
    DeckOfCards myDeck;
    myDeck.shuffle();
    myDeck.dealCard();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::random_shuffle()` is usually a strong possibility.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? The cards aren't in random order? The cards don't exist at all? Duplicate cards? Program crashes?

Comment: Your deck initialization isn't correct either, nor is your Card::toString() member.

Comment: It would list the cards in order, it is working now though.

Answer (score 2):

This is the reason your cards are "dealt" in order:

```
void dealCard(){
    for(int i=0; i<13; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
            cout << toString(i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

You don't use the deck at all.  You just print them out in order.

Try this:

```
cout << toString(deck[i][j].face, deck[i][j].suit);
```

You should really write a `Card::toString` function with no parameters and let it use its `face` and `suit` members.

```
cout << deck[i][j].toString();
```

For the record, I really don't like you you arranged your deck as a 2D array.  There is absolutely no need to do that.  And I like it even less that `DeckOfCards` inherits from `Card`.

Since I'm nitpicking, you don't need a whole deck-sized array for your temporary swap variable.  You just need one `Card`.  In fact, you ought to use `std::swap` instead.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot, sorry if my code frustrated you lol. I'm not very computer savvy

Comment: No problem.  Stick at it, and you'll eventually make fewer mistakes, or at least develop the ablity to find and correct mistakes yourself.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, I think your initial assignment of the deck is not working.

```
DeckOfCards(){  
    for(int i=0; i<13; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
            deck[i][j].setData(face, suit);
         }
    }
}
```

You're setting every card to '(face, suit)'.  What are those at this point?  I think you mean to set them to '(i, j)'.  I'm surprised this compiles, because face and suit are only declared as properties of the card object.

Comment: Thanks, that made me feel really stupid lol. I got it working now though.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you avoid using arrays and use [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), and that you use [std::random_shuffle](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/) to shuffle your deck.

Here is quick edit I made to your code to show you how it is done

```
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Card{
public:
    int face;
    int suit;
    void setData(int f, int s){
        face = f;
        suit = s;
    }
};

class DeckOfCards:public Card{
public:
    std::vector<Card> deck;

    void shuffle(){
        srand (time(0));
        std::random_shuffle(deck.begin(), deck.end());
    }

    DeckOfCards(){  
        deck.reserve(13 * 4);
        for(int i=0; i<13; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
                Card card;
                card.setData(i, j);
                deck.push_back(card);
            }
        }
    }

};

int main(){
    DeckOfCards myDeck;
    myDeck.shuffle();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My professor hasn't taught us to use vectors yet so this is greek to me lol. Thanks anyways though